# app:theme now is deprecated

Tags: android, styles, themes, android-appcompat

I were using android very fine from yesterday but today when i ran my app through `intellijIDEA` it gives me :

```
I/AppCompatViewInflater﹕ app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
```

**my styles is :**

```
    <resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Base">

    </style>

    <style name="Theme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

what is the problem and how can i solve it?

thanks in advance,

**UPDATE** :my `toolbar.xml` file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                               xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                               android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                               android:layout_width="match_parent"
                               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                               android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                               android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                               local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                               local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

---

**android sdk tools : 24.3.3**

**android sdk build tools :22**

**android support library : 22.2**

Comment: are you using toolbar ?

Comment: thank you @NileshJarad, yes i am using that

Comment: can you post xml code for the toolbar ?

Comment: i will update my post

Comment: posted answer check it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83030/discussion-between-nilesh-jarad-and-mostafa-jamareh).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
           android:id="@+id/toolbar"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
           android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
           android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
          />
```

Comment: it gives me *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Out of memory

Comment: are you using any service?

Comment: the error is from another part of application it may from service or something that creates` out of Memory`

Comment: Are you sure about  android:popupTheme?